# Transpose data from rows into Column

Tags: python, rows

I am new to `python` and I was trying to use DataFrames to see if I can achieve the desired output

This is the input:

```
            Data = {
            NAME = Jack
            AGE  = 25
            CITY = NYC
        }
            Data = {
            NAME = Jill
            AGE =  35
            CITY = Boston
        }
```

and it keeps repeating in the same sequence. I tried to do with `transpose`. This is the output I need:

```
   NAME AGE CITY
Jack  25  NYC

Jill  35  Boston
```

But I don't think this is the right approach. Please can you provide some guidance?

Comment: How does your dataframe look like?

Comment: Why don't you simply store a list of dictionaries?? You know for each element each key corresponds to a column. Is there any reason to make it a data frame?If so, just append them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the input is in dictionary form,  this will work

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([{
            'NAME' : 'Jack',
            'AGE'  : 25,
            'CITY' : 'NYC'
        }.values(),
          {
            'NAME' : 'Jill',
            'AGE' :  35,
            'CITY' : 'Boston'
        }.values()], columns = {'NAME','AGE','CITY'}).set_index('NAME')

print (x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the input in such a fashion to get your data populated correctly

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'NAME':['Jack','Jill'],'AGE':[25,35],'CITY':['NYC','BOSTON']})
```